# Weird whitespace appearing on Joomla

Tags: html, css, firebug, whitespace

While polishing my site I noticed there was some unwanted space between 2 elements, so I decided to remove it. But looking at the source, I found this:

[image: screenshot]

Please check it by yourself, there's no trace of this server-side. Live page here: http://www.playersonline.com.ar/guias

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can only confirm that I am seeing some odd 'dot' characters in the same position as you indicate in the source. It must be something that your code is outputting... stuff just doesn't show up on its own :-), but I don't have any suggestions as to what or where to look for a solution. Sorry.

Comment: have you tried looking at it with no js on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where the mysterious whitespace is coming from, but modifying your `#k2Container` CSS will solve the problem for you:

```
#k2Container {
    padding:0; 
    position: relative; 
    top: -20px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

Comment: Meh, dirty but works :D. This thing is cursed anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checked in Firebug, Chrome, Firefox Webmaster Tools, and via validator.  Half indicate stray characters.  Half don't.

Often times, you can solve an issue like this with Firefox Web Developer Tool's "View Generated Source"  which is important for browsers like Firefox that are intelligent enough to fix the problems themselves (unlike IE I might add)  Non breaking spaces are a great example of an element that can toy with IE but will never show up on Firefox with this feature.  Here's the link if you don't have it:  http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

I'd say take 20 minutes to grep your code again for the string " . "  If that doesn't find a result, by all means consider Pat's suggestion.  That's one heck of a lot of divs to deal with!